# Error Elements of a set are identified only by their value and don't have any separate index or key to select with,

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, packer

I'm getting this error when I do terraform apply

```
Error: Invalid index
│
│   on deployBuildAWS.tf line 57, in resource "aws_instance" "packer_instance":
│   57:   subnet_id              = data.aws_subnet_ids.packer_subnet.ids[0]
│
│ Elements of a set are identified only by their value and don't have any separate index or key to select with, so it's only possible to perform operations across all elements of the set.
```

Here are the relevant bits of my code

```
data "aws_subnet_ids" "packer_subnet" {
  vpc_id = data.aws_vpcs.packer_vpc.ids[0]

  tags = {
    service = "packerBuildDeploySubnet"
  }
}

...

resource "aws_instance" "packer_instance" {
  ami                    = data.aws_ami.packer_image.id
  instance_type          = "t2.small"
  subnet_id              = data.aws_subnet_ids.packer_subnet.ids[0]
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["${data.aws_security_groups.packer_security_group.ids[0]}"]
  key_name               = var.packerKeyName


}
```

I've tried the following but it didn't improve the situation

```
    data "aws_subnet_ids" "packer_subnet" {
     
    
     for_each = data.aws_subnet_ids.packer_subnet.ids
    id = each.value
    }
```

For completeness , here are some other blocks of code

```
    data "aws_vpcs" "packer_vpc" {
      tags = {
        service = "packerBuildDeployVPC"
      }
    }
    
    data "aws_subnet_ids" "packer_subnet" {
      vpc_id = data.aws_vpcs.packer_vpc.ids[0]
    
      tags = {
        service = "packerBuildDeploySubnet"
      }
    }
    
    data "aws_security_groups" "packer_security_group" {
      tags = {
        service = "packerBuildDeploySecurityGroup"
      }
    }
```

I'm using terraform 1.3.7 and packer 1.8.4...I've tried with various different versions of Terraform but still getting very similar errors..
Provider =

```
provider "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws" {
  version     = "4.50.0"
```

I'm obviously quite new to terraform, can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Show us `data.aws_vpcs.packer_vpc`

Comment: @Paolo I've edited my post with the blocks you wanted to see  please look again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is correct: the `set` type in any language is unordered and therefore elements cannot be accessed by index. Since you only want to select one subnet, we can fix this by only attempting to Read one subnet:

```
data "aws_subnet" "packer_subnet" { # Read single AWS subnet
  vpc_id = data.aws_vpcs.packer_vpc.ids[0]

  tags = {
    service = "packerBuildDeploySubnet"
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "packer_instance" {
  ami                    = data.aws_ami.packer_image.id
  instance_type          = "t2.small"
  subnet_id              = data.aws_subnet.packer_subnet.id # string value in data attribute
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["${data.aws_security_groups.packer_security_group.ids[0]}"]
  key_name               = var.packerKeyName
}
```

Note you will likely have similar issues with `data.ws_security_groups.packer_security_group` and `data.aws_vpcs.packer_vpc` which are not shown in the question, and therefore will need to apply similar fixes to those as well.

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for this , I'll give it a try and come back with the results

Comment: works like a charm.....much appreciated....but can you explain what you mean when you say  "set type in any language is unordered and therefore elements cannot be accessed by index" ?

Comment: Lists can use indexes, but sets are unordered hence they don't have indexes and you can't fetch elements of a set the same way you would when using lists. I think. :)